# Stand-alone NetBeans-compatible .form editor

Tags: java, forms, netbeans, gui-designer, matisse

Is there a stand-alone GUI designer that can read and write the .form files that NetBeans (Matisse) generates? I like the GUI designer, but I don't want all the overhead of a complete Java IDE just to create and edit .form XML files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check out [JFormDesigner](http://www.jformdesigner.com/). I know it can import Netbeans .form files, but I'm not sure how it works vice versa. Available both as stand-alone and as plug-in to severals IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably none available. The form editor has several features that are not trivial to implement, such as custom controls and code.
It's simply to complex and not useful enough.